# Анимация движения объекта по траектории графика со сглаженными линиями

Tags: javascript, ajax, svg, canvas, поиск-библиотек

Нужно сделать сделать анимацию при клике.

Есть кривая и на ней расположены точки, и есть один кораблик.
Задача состоит в том, чтобы при клике на точку этот кораблик перемещался по траектории кривой.

Можете подсказать как лучше всего это выполнить (библиотек, плагинов и фреймворков)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все что нужно для изготовления подобного это `path.getTotalLength()` `path.getPointAtLength()` и совсем немного математики:

```js
let count = 7,
    len = track.getTotalLength(),
    seg = len / (count + 1),
    pos = seg,
    target = seg;
    
svg.innerHTML += Array(count).fill(0).map((e, i) => {
  let len = seg * (i + 1), p = track.getPointAtLength(len);
  return "<g transform=translate("+[p.x, p.y]+") class"+(i?'':'=active')+">" +
         "  <circle data-len="+len+" r=6></circle>" +
         "  <rect rx=5 ry=5 x=-20 y=16 width=40 height=19></rect>" +
         "  <text y=30>"+(2001+i)+"</text>"+
         "</g>";
}).join('');

render();

function render() {
  let dp = target - pos;
  pos += Math.abs(dp) < 1 ? 0 : Math.sign(dp);
  let p1 = track.getPointAtLength(pos),
      p2 = track.getPointAtLength(pos + 1),
      a = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
  ship.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+p1.x+","+p1.y+")rotate("+a+")");
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
}

let circles = document.querySelectorAll('circle');
circles.forEach(c => c.onclick = e => {
  circles.forEach(c1 => c1.parentNode.classList.toggle('active', c===c1))
  target = +c.dataset.len;
});
```

```css
#ship {
  fill: #75e3c6;
}

#track {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 2px 5px;
}

circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

rect {
  fill: transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

text {
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  user-select: none;
}

.active circle {
  fill: #e53326;
  stroke: #e53326;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.active rect {
  fill: #e53326;
}

.active text {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<svg width=600 height=170 id="svg">
  <path id="track" d="m20,140c50,0,0,-50,150,-50c50,0,0,-50,150,-50c50,0,0,50,150,50c50,0,0,50,150,50"></path>
  <path id="ship" d="m-10,-5l-10,-10l15,3l5,-10l5,10l15,-3l-10,10z"></path>
</svg>
```