# SVG Привязка растровых объектов к пути (path)

Tags: html, css, svg

Не могу найти информацию по привязке объекта к пути.

Имеется следующий элемент SVG:

```css
svg{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
svg path{
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path id="curve" d="M64,287 C277,329 191,140 445,210" />
    <text style="font-size: 24px;">
        <textPath xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">test text</textPath>
    </text>
    <image href="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/user-male-circle.png" rx=5 width="50px" height="50px">
        <animateMotion
            dur="5s"
            repeatCount="3"
            rotate="auto"
            restart="whenNotActive">
            <mpath xlink:href="#curve" />
        </animateMotion>
    </image>
</svg>
```

Создал своего франкенштейна из ответов на SO, где нашел текст привязанный к пути и картинку, которая привязана только по анимации.

**Задача состоит в том, чтобы просто привязать объект image к пути подобно тексту.** Но гуглежка в течении часа не дала плоды и поэтому я задаю этот вопрос здесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать keyPoints в одной и той же точке, вот что получается:

```css
svg{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
svg path{
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 160 500 500">
    <path id="curve" d="M64,287 C277,329 191,140 445,210" />
    <text style="font-size: 24px;">
        <textPath xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">test text</textPath>
    </text>
    <image href="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/user-male-circle.png" width="50px" height="50px" transform="translate(-25,-25)">
        <animateMotion calcMode="linear" keyPoints="0.5; 0.5" keyTimes="0; 1" rotate="auto">
            <mpath xlink:href="#curve" />
        </animateMotion>
    </image>
</svg>
```

PS: я так же на 50% подвинул изображение влево и вверх

Comment: Черт, это конечно превосходное решение, но мне почему-то кажется что есть менее костыльные способы магнитить картинку к пути

Comment: @MoloF на js знаю способ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011949/188366

Comment: Спасибо но лучше не надо, js тут излишен и писать на нем такую простую работу будет не комильфо. Должна же быть какая-то ерунда как у textPath

Comment: @MoloF сделал по центру пути

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы привязать картинку к пути, можно воспользоваться [маркерами](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=855)

В роли маркера может выступать любая фигура SVG и в том числе любое растровое изображение.

```
 <marker id="User" viewBox="0 0 50 50" refX="0" refY="27"
        markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
        markerWidth="50" markerHeight="50" > 
        <image href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/76W3b.png"  width="50px" height="50px"/>
    </marker>
```

Маркеры имеют три места посадки на линию:

`marker-start`, `marker-mid`, `marker-end`
  Если нужно разместить маркер на середине линии, то выбираем - `marker-mid` Также необходимо учитывать, что такого наименования маркеры размещаются на переломных точках и их может быть несколько.

refX="0" refY="27" - атрибуты для позиционирования маркера относительно `path`

```html
<style>
svg{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
svg path{
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
</style>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <marker id="User" viewBox="0 0 50 50" refX="0" refY="27"
        markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
        markerWidth="50" markerHeight="50" > 
  <image href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/76W3b.png"  width="50px" height="50px"/>
 </marker> 
  </defs>
    <path id="curve" d="M64 287C170.5 308 202.3 271.3 239.1 238 276 204.8 318 175 445 210" marker-mid="url(#User)" />
    <text dy="-5" style="font-size: 28px;">
        <textPath xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="40%" text-anchor="middle" >test</textPath>
    </text>
  <text dy="-5" style="font-size: 28px;">
        <textPath xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="65%" text-anchor="middle" >text</textPath>
    </text>
    
</svg>
```

- Допустим не устраивает нас красная линия на заднем фоне.

  Можно усложнить маркер и сделать картинку непрозрачной, для этого добавим на задний фон непрозрачную окружность  `<circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="white" />`
- Или нужно увеличить размер изображения

  Для этого увеличиваем регион действия маркера:

  `markerWidth="70" markerHeight="70"`

```html
<style>
svg{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
svg path{
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
</style>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <marker id="User" viewBox="0 0 50 50" refX="0" refY="27"
        markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
        markerWidth="70" markerHeight="70" > 
   <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="white" />
  <image href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/76W3b.png"  width="50px" height="50px"/>
 </marker> 
  </defs>
    <path id="curve" d="M64 287C170.5 308 202.3 271.3 239.1 238 276 204.8 318 175 445 210" marker-mid="url(#User)" />
    <text dy="-5" style="font-size: 28px;">
        <textPath xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="40%" text-anchor="middle" >test</textPath>
    </text>
  <text dy="-5" style="font-size: 28px;">
        <textPath xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="70%" text-anchor="middle" >text</textPath>
    </text>
    
</svg>
```

Comment: @MoloF Благодарю. Что-нибудь нужно дополнительно пояснить?

Comment: нет, всё как всегда чётко и понятно. Спасибо большое за ответы!